# Display only one Teacher Id on Teachers Column in DatagridView

Tags: c#, sql, database, filter, datagridview

I am doing a **application for a school using C# and database with SQL Server Management Studio** and in one of the forms I want that when the **teacher logged in only view the records from his**, in order to hide the records from another teachers, so in the part of the code when I display all the teachers in datagridview I want to filter the "ProfessorId", column teacher id referent, to the id of the teacher that logged in while the application is running.

I am using my table for show classes from each teacher (ProfessoresTurmas), the column contain:

- Id Primary Key
- ProfessorId(Teacher's Id) Foreign Key from Teachers Table
- CursoId(Teacher's Course) Foreign Key from Courses Table
- TurmaId(Teacher's Class) Foreign Key from Classes Table

[Image of the records of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEfSA.png)

[Image of the table's design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qICiW.png)

[Query working in sql server management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOpw4.png)

Thats the code that worked but only with the id that I wrote in the code, "Pr1" is one of the ids from the table but I want to detect automatically what's the teacher's id that is logged in:

```
private void DisplayTeachers()
        {
            Con.Open();
            string Query = "Select * from ProfessorTurmas where ProfessorId = 'Pr1'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, Con);
            SqlCommandBuilder Builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DataGridView_student.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            Con.Close();
        }
```

Thats the code that I tried to wrote instead of 'Pr1' with UserCache.IdUser, thats the teacher's id logged in while the application is running:

```
private void DisplayTeachers()
        {
            Con.Open();
            string Query = "Select * from ProfessorTurmas where ProfessorId = " + UserCache.IdUser;
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(Query, Con);
            SqlCommandBuilder Builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
            var ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DataGridView_student.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            Con.Close();
        }
```

But shows me this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Pr1'.'

In this line:

sda.Fill(ds);

Comment: string Query = "Select * from ProfessorTurmas where ProfessorId = '" + UserCache.IdUser+"'";

Comment: you just missed to put the value in quotes

Comment: Use a parameterized query to avoid sql injection

Comment: Actually considering @Serg 's comment would solve the problem more sustainably

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I will apply what serg suggested too, I forgot to defend my application from sql injection.

Comment: Your error is that the result is "where id = Pr1" instead of "id = 'Pr1'" (with quotes, so sql server knows it's a string).
As other say, with parameters you will protect against sql injection, and also against this kind of errors.